# How to make URL bold?

Tags: urls, bold

```
%url package
\usepackage{url}

%code that makes URL font the same
\newcommand{\urlwofont}[1]
{
\urlstyle{same}\url{#1}
}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=8cm, scale=0.55]{../Figures/~}
    \caption{\small ~).
\protect\urlwofont{http://www.google.com/~}}
    \label{~}
\end{figure}
```

I am using this sequence when stating reference URL for figures.

However, how can I make this URL bold?? I tried to use `{\bf}`, but I don`t know where to put it or how to use it. Can anybody give advice for this?

Comment: Hi Michita, welcome to tex exchange! I indented your code snippets by clicking on the `{}` icon, and used backticks to highlight your `{\bf}`. I also removed the thanks- it may sound strange, but the best way to thank folks is to 'upvote' (and hopefully, accept) their answers :)

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{url}  % or \usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Normal font:
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}


Bold:
\def\UrlFont{\bfseries}
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You may use `UrlFont` like this:

```
\def\UrlFont{\bfseries\rmfamily}  
\url{This is bold roman}
```