# Make all \href text bold

Tags: formatting, hyperref, bold

For url's, I know the bare URL can be made bold, as illustrated in this question: [How to make URL bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47468/how-to-make-url-bold).

How can I do the same thing, for an entire document, for the text field of `\href`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine `\href` to always use `\href[.]{..}{\bfseries ...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro,xparse}

\LetLtxMacro\oldhref\href
\RenewDocumentCommand{\href}{o m m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\oldhref[#1]{#2}{\bfseries #3}}
    {\oldhref{#2}{\bfseries #3}}%
}

\begin{document}

\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{\TeX.SE}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want all your urls bold using `\href`, you can redefine the `\href` macro by adding `\bfseries` to the second argument as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldhref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\oldhref{#1}{\bfseries#2}}

\begin{document}

Bold font:

\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}

\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This doesn't reference `\href` at all

Comment: @Adam_G  - I modified for the case of `href`. Please see my edit.