# Format cleveref labels including names

Tags: hyperref, cleveref

I'm trying to emphasize my figure references with bold text. When referencing a labeled figure with `\cref{fig:mylabel}` I get the correct text `Abbildung 1`, however I'm having trouble formatting it.

[image]

I'm using the packages `hyperref` and `cleveref` with a German document setting. As per [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) there is the option `\crefdefaultlabelformat`, however when I try to make the entire label bold (so including the name) with `\crefdefaultlabelformat{\bfseries#2#1#3}` only the number reference will get emphasized. Same is true for `\creflabelformat{figure}...`.

There is also the option to format the links provided by hyperref, but I was unable to find something that only targets these specific links.

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{\bfseries#2#1#3}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Some image}
    \label{fig:mylabel}
\end{figure}

This should all be bold \(\rightarrow\) \cref{fig:mylabel}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the aim is to have just figure references bold, you can do

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefformat{figure}{#2\bfseries\figurename~#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \caption{Some image}
    \label{fig:mylabel}
\end{figure}

This should all be bold \cref{fig:mylabel} and this shouldn't.

\end{document}
```

If you really want *all* `\cref` produced text to be in boldface, you can patch `\@cref`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@cref}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \caption{Some image}
    \label{fig:mylabel}
\end{figure}

This should all be bold \cref{fig:mylabel} and this shouldn't.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This makes the conjunctions bold as well when using multi-references. Is there a way to make only the labels bold?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone has a more cref/hyperref native solution.

But in the meanwhile what works is to just wrap `cref` with `bfseries`. Inspired by [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351654/97536) to make it a bit less cumbersome, we can automatize this wrapping by first saving the `cref` under another name e.g. `oldcref`:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldcref\cref
```

And then redefining the `cref` with the wrapped one:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cref}{m}{\bfseries\oldcref{#1}} % m here means one mandatory argument
```

All together for your MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}

% simply wrap cref by bfseries
\usepackage{letltxmacro,xparse}
\LetLtxMacro\oldcref\cref
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cref}{m}{\bfseries\oldcref{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Some image}
    \label{fig:mylabel}
\end{figure}

This should all be bold \(\rightarrow\) \cref{fig:mylabel}
\end{document}
```

[image]