# Color all \cref cleveref

Tags: color, cleveref

I am unable to get this to work, I am trying to use, `\creflabelformat{*}{\textcolor{darkred}{#1}}` to color all labels or links with the same color however, this does not appear to work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}

\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm
\unitlength = 1mm


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=it, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalise]{cleveref} % Better in-doc refs

\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{153,0,0}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\creflabelformat{*}{\textcolor{darkred}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\small\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
    \caption{Comparisons}\label{tab1}\\
    \hline\rowcolor{Black}
    Column & Column & Column & Column & 
    Column & Column & Column \\ \hline  
    \raggedright Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & \\ \hline
    \raggedright Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & \\ \hline
    \raggedright Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & Hello & \\ \hline
\end{longtable}


\begin{table*}
    \normalsize
    \caption{Static analysis of selected wallets.}\label{tab2}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|lllllll|lllllll|}
        \hline
        & \rot{Bitcoin Wallet} & \rot{Bither} & \rot{BRD} & \rot{Dash wallet} & \rot{Electrum} & \rot{Monerujo} & \rot{Simple Bitcoin } & \rot{Bitcoin.com} & \rot{Mycelium} & \rot{Coinomi} & \rot{Jaxx} & \rot{Copay} & \rot{Airbitz} & \rot{Samourai} \\
        \hline
        Leaks (FlowDroid) & 0 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 4 & ? \\
        Leak to ext.~storage & - & - & - & - & + & - & + & - & - & - & + & + & + & - \\
        XSS WebView & - & - & + & - & - & - & - & + & - & + & + & + & + & - \\
        Insecure conn. & + & + & - & + & - & - & + & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
        Leak into logs & + & + & + & + & + & + & + & + & + & + & + & + & + & + \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    %}
    \label{tab:static-analysis}
\end{table*}

Please refer to \cref{tab1} and \cref{tab2} above. 

\end{document}\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
```

**EDIT:** I know that, `\creflabelformat{table}` with different names, `\creflabelformat{figure}` etc. But, I want one definition that applies to all, and includes the **Figure/Table/Section** names.

[image]

*Ignore the Blue parts. Focus is on the Red parts, meaning, that's what I want with full name and numbers. But, I need one definition that applies to them all.*

Comment: Does `\creflabelformat{table}{\color{darkred}#1#2#3}` do what you want?

Comment: Off-topic: To maximize the interoperability of the `xcolor` and `colortbl` package, they shouldn't be loaded independently. Instead, load them both via `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill, **NO!**

Comment: @PeterGrill - Better still, `\creflabelformat{table}{#2\textcolor{darkred}{#1}#3}`.

Comment: @Mico please see my EDIT.

Comment: @PeterGrill, please see edit.

Comment: @Mico, I want to have same color on every occurrence of `\cref` usage in the text.

Comment: you could simply color the links with `\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=darkred}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, unfortunately, that colors my **TOC**, and the **\gls** acronyms used in text.

Comment: imho cleveref has no interface, but you could patch an internal command, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609191/2388

Comment: What you're asking for the `cleveref` package to provide a new and likely-not-trivial-to-implement feature. Feature requests are off-topic for the TeX.SE site and should, instead, be directed to the package's author and maintainer. Unfortunately, the author of the `cleveref` package does not appear to respond to emails anymore. You could try to contact him directly, but chances that you'll get a usable response are unfortunately quite slim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution.**

*Default:*

```
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,breaklinks,
  linktoc=section,
  linkcolor=darkred,
  linkbordercolor=white,
  citecolor=darkred,
  urlcolor=darkred,
  pdfborder = {0 0 1}
}
```

*For TOC, List of Figures, and Tables, a local modification,*

```
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\tableofcontents
}
```

*To set all **\gls{}** links to black,*

```
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
```

Comment: The `colorlinks=true` option makes the `linkbordercolor` and `pdfborder` options unnecessary. Rather than specify the option `breaklinks`, I'd load the `xurl` package.

Comment: @Mico, what is `xurl` and why is that better?

Comment: [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) is a LaTeX package. It allows line breaks at arbitrary postions in URL strings. It's far more fliexible than hyperref's `breakurl` option.